# Multiple inputs into a R function

Tags: r, function, input, knitr, rnw

So I currently have this code below in a file, pullsec.R

```
pullsec <- function(session=NULL){
  if(is.null(session))  session<-1
  stopifnot(is.numeric(session))
  paste("Session",1:10)[session]
}
```

In an .Rnw file, I call on this pullsec.R and choose session number 3 by:

```
source("pullsec.R")
setsec <- pullsec(3)
```

which would pull all of the rows where the column Session has data values of "Session 3"

I would like to add another block to pullsec.R that would allow me to pull data for a second column, Sessions where the data in that column is Sessions 1-2, Sessions 3-4, Session 5-6, etc. But I'm not sure how to modify the pullsec block to accept multiple inputs.

I had tried many solutions but no bite. My most naive solution is:

```
pullsec2 <- function(sessions1=NULL,sessions2=NULL){
  if(is.null(sessions1))  sessions1<-1
  stopifnot(is.numeric(session1))
  paste("Sessions",1:10,"-",1:10)[sessions]
}
```

Comment: So what parameters so you want to pass to `pullsec2` and what so you want the result to be?

Comment: I'd like to pass 2 integers to `pullsec` (say int1 and int2) and the result should be "Sessions int1-int2"

Answer (score 0):

either of these would do:

```
pullsec2 <- function(session1=1,session2=2){
  stopifnot(is.numeric(session1))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(session2))
  paste0("Sessions ",session1,'-',session2)
}
pullsec2(3,4)

pullsec2 <- function(sessions=1){
  stopifnot(is.numeric(sessions))
  paste("Sessions",paste0(sessions,collapse="-"))
}

pullsec2(3:4)
```